# Exchange How To Deliver Main Mail and Redirected Mail To Mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, hosted-exchange, email

My client requested an employee's mails to be blind carbon copied to himself. We did it with a simple rule. After that he told me if somebody sends email to both him and his employee, he only receives 1 mail. He insist on receiving 2 mails for both himself and his employee, because he archives all of his employee's mails in a subfolder.

It's really a weird request and I don't know is it possible. Is it possible? How can I do that?

edit--

I am adding rules to the transport not to client, he doesn't want the employee to be able to delete rule.

Answer (score 2):

You stated that you achieved this with a rule but you didn't state if this was a Transport rule on the Exchange server or an email client rule on the client.

What you can do is to set the email forwarding option in the Delivery Options on the Mail Flow Settings tab of the mailbox properties pages of the employee. Check the "Forward to:" checkbox, select the managers mailbox as the forward destination, check the "Deliver message to both forwarding address and mailbox" checkbox and apply.

Comment: I set the rule as a transport rule, not client rule. He doesn't want the user to be able to delete or deactivate rule. Is it the only way to do that on client side?

Comment: You missed my point. You can set the forwarding options on the mailbox in the Exchange Management Console. The user doesn't have access (or shouldn't have access) to the mailbox object in EMC. This is not a client side setting, it is a mailbox setting accessed from the EMC.

Comment: Now I see. I am managing a hosted Exchange so should do that on EMS. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to do that on EMS. I couldn't find so...

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351134(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: this is not doing what I need. This method sends a copy to forwarding address but my client's request occurs if somebody sends an email to him and his employee sametime. He wants 2 duplicate email in his own mailbox, one in incoming folder, one in a special folder with a rule. But exchange sends only one copy. It doesn't process the rule if forwarding address is already in "to" header. Is it possible to receive a duplicate mail?